# Is there any way to register any event listener in CYPRESS HOOKS which listens for that particular event throughout the test execution

Tags: cypress

Example: Let suppose my tests are running and there is one session expire popup which appears anytime while test execution which we are not aware off that when it will appear

So i want a way or any kind of listener in CYPRESS which i can register globally and keeps on listening for that session expire popup event in Hooks Can someone please help

Comment: May be `cy.spy()` will help https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spy#Command-Log Or `Cypress.promise()` https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise#Rejected-test-promises-do-not-fail-tests

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i have to register the listener globally like in plugin.js not on, before or after any specific element

Comment: In theory, if you register it like it is written on the second link - it will be global, though it will be up to you to write a working command. I see such file `/support/events.js` as a default file in the cypress package